# Does Gamora's species have males?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Watching [*Avengers: Infinity War* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/), we see Gamora and her mother. There's also a bunch of people during a flashback on her home planet, who all look female--maybe there's a quick glimpse of some males, but I'm not sure. There seems to be very few males on that planet, if any.

**Does Gamora's species have males?**

I'm hoping for an unequivocal answer (e.g. details of Gamora's biological father), not just a quick glimpse at some scene where I'm left thinking "maybe they're male".

Comment: Is there male Xenomorph? Is there a female Predator? Does groot has gender or do they identify as Tree? Did the Ents had a ring of power, and just took them too long to open the package that Sauron was already defeated?

Comment: I explained the motivation in the question... if you look at the scene from Gamora's home planet, they're virtually all female (I didn't see a single male, but it seems I missed one).  If there's a 0.5 probability of a random person being male, it's improbable that a whole village can be shown without easily spotting one.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the comics ([*Gamora Vol 1* #4](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Gamora_Vol_1_4)), some male Zen-Whoberis/Zehoberei are shown:

[image: Gamora Vol 1 panel showing male Zen-Whoberis/Zehoberei]

They are the same species as Gamora, who is shown in the middle. It's also worth mentioning that Gamora calls them her "relatives".

---

In the movie canon, what Gamora says in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 1* heavily implies she has a birth father:

> **Gamora:** My father didn't stress diplomacy.
>   **Peter Quill:** Thanos?
>   **Gamora:** He's not my father. When Thanos took my home world, he killed my parents in front of me. He tortured me, turned me into a weapon. When he said he was going to destroy an entire planet for Ronan, I...I couldn't stand by and...

Comment: I'd say that's more than implication. She literally mentions a father then literally confirms she's not talking about Thanos (her adoptive father). Granted, I suppose she could have had another adoptive father before Thanos 

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit She says Thanos is not her father and that she has parents. Someone with two or more mothers (or a tri-sex species) could say the same. Assuming that one of the parents is a father is begging the question.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Except she literally uses the phrase "my father" (and tells us that she's not talking about Thanos). Why would she call a mother "my father"? So it's not an assumption, she literally told us the answer!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I will have to rewatch to make sure, but I think the first time she is referring to Thanos, then clarifying the relationship when asked.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Why would she call Thanos "my father" in one line, then say "he's not my father" literally the next sentence? Sorry, not buying it! She referred to a father, Quill assumed she meant Thanos, Gamora corrected him; i.e. she was never talking about Thanos. Seems clear from the quoted discourse.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham If Thanos is not her father, then it makes no logical sense that she would be referring to Thanos as her father in the first line.

Comment: @bornfromanegg likewise it is not  'logical' that she and Nebula refer to each other as sister, but they do so. The family relationships are a little conflicted, and dialog appearing to contradict itself is a one technique to reflect such conflict. People do this in real life; I have friends who will say exactly the same kind of thing - "my sister, well she's not my sister as I was adopted, but my sister, ...")  If everyone only made logical statements in a film it wouldn't have a heart worth watching.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Perhaps the word 'logical' was not what I meant. What I meant is that the exchange as a whole simply does not make sense if Thanos is her father. Your example sentence makes sense, but it is different to the exchange above.

Answer (score 28):

## Yes

Watching the scene where Thanos takes Gamora we see what appear to be males of her species in the background. This guy in the background appears to be one (ignore the giant watermark I couldn't find a better video easily):

[image: Gamora first meets Thanos]

Comment: Whilst I realise this isn't exactly what you're after _"I'm hoping for an unequivocal answer (e.g. details of Gamora's biological father), not just a quick glimpse at some scene where I'm left thinking "maybe they're male"."_ [Laurel's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/96600/45378) adds everything else I could so no point repeating information.

Answer (score 1):

Gamora is a member of the Zehoberei, who live on the planet Zen-Whoberi.  By all Marvel sources, the Zehoberei are a humanoid race.  They have children, which would indicate that there are both male and female Zehoberei necessary for procreation.

Also, Gamora herself is mentioned as being female in the movies, and if all Zehoberei were unisex or whatever the previous argument was that led to those downvotes I received, then there'd be no need to specify that she was a single sex, a sex which exists in other humanoid races like our own.

Comment: Having children does not necessarily infer there are two sexes, in a species we don't know very much about. We already have species in real life that reproduce without a partner of opposite gender.

Comment: A long term booty call would imply having all the correct equipment. Are those not mammary glands on her chest?

Comment: @Gnemlock - And those species you speak of...  They're Humanoid?

Comment: @Gnemlock *imply

Comment: @Mazura There are a lot of ways to have a "long term booty call" that don't require "having all the correct equipment".

Comment: If Gamora is ever referred to as a *she* or a *her*, then the only thing we can do is ask the author if they're using those words as [their preferred gender neutral term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_pronoun).

Comment: @Gremlock.  "...does not necessarily _imply_..." The speaker/writer/established facts _imply_ that something else is true.  The listener/reader/observer _infers_ that something else is true.  This is not a trivial distinction:  I have inferred from your comment that you believe Johnny has made a fallacious inference that is not truly implied by the facts.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: "Humanoid" typically just means "resembling a human" or "shaped like a human"; it's not a very precise term, and doesn't imply too much about the biological details. (Heck, it doesn't even imply that they *are* biological; you can have "humanoid robots".)

Comment: It is obvious, given the other answers, that there *are* males; but it is also obvious that there is much better proof than "because there are females". Most of this answer still relies on assumptions based off 'how it works in real life'. It's not real life, it's fiction; it could work however the creator wants. You could say Gamora is mentioned as female because she looks female. I could come up with at least half a dozen ways it *could* work, but it seems unnecessary. I'd consider withdrawing my down-vote if any concrete evidence was added regarding males.

Comment: @JohnnyBones The green robot that is the Android logo is also humanoid